# Optimizing QPlainTextEdit Widget When Bombarded with Data?

Tags: c++, linux, qt

So basically what I have is a Qt application that has a main GUI thread and a worker thread.

The worker thread is something like this:

```
void Client::readResults(int msgqid, pid_t pid)
{
    int ret;
    msg_t message;

    connect(this, SIGNAL(dataReceived(QString)), this, SLOT(updateDisplay(QString)));
    connect(this, SIGNAL(doneProcessing(QString)), this, SLOT(updateStatus(QString)));

    for (;;)
    {
        ret = msgrcv(msgqid, &message, MSGSIZE, pid, 0);
        if (ret == -1)
        {
            showStatusBarError("msgrcv");
            return;
        }

        if (ret > 0)
        {
            emit dataReceived(QLatin1String(message.info));

            if (message.is_eof)
            {
                emit doneProcessing("Done!");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

All it does is it reads from a message queue and emits a signal that causes a QPlainTextEdit widget from the main GUI thread (that spawned this thread) to call appendPlainText(message.info) so that the data received from the message queue is appended to the widget.

The problem is if I'm reading huge chunks of data from the queue (it's actually a text file around 30MB or more), the whole GUI just hangs until the worker thread finishes. Is there a way to make it not hang and for the user to actually see the QPlainTextEdit widget scrolling as it received data from the worker thread?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you feed the data to the TextEdit in chunks? I.e. manually split up the message into digestible chunks? Another concern is the cast to QLatin1String - this creates a a new temporary, the data from messsage.info is copied into it, and then it is probably copied again to be sent across the slot as a value. Make sure you are not doing any unnecessary conversions or copies.

Comment: @AlexanderKondratskiy The 30MB file is actually read 256 bytes at a time (by another process) before being placed into the message queue. So for each emit dataReceived(), message.info is 256 characters.

Comment: Hmm that's strange. I don't think the problem lies in the QPlainTextEdit, as I have used it to print large logs before. Might be a dumb suggestion, but where is the Client object created? Hopefully it was instantiated within the worker thread, and not the GUI thread as all the slots would actually trigger on the main thread.

Comment: @AlexanderKondratskiy It's not a dumb suggestion if the person you're talking to is dumb :) Yes, that's actually how I did it. I only have 1 class (Client) which is also the GUI that has the signals and slots. The way I started the worker is through a button push slot (ie. If button in GUI is pressed, call QtConcurrent::run(this, &Client::readResults, msgqid, pid)). How bad did I mess up?

Comment: Maybe it's not as bad as I thought. I'll get back to you once I think about this.

Comment: So I tried creating a separate class that inherits from QThread which is instantiated in main. I still have the same problem unfortunately. I think the issue is that I'm sending too many dataReceived() signals which causes the GUI to update the widget everytime and hang. If that's the case then I'm not sure how threading could solve the problem since the GUI has to update eventually. Thank you very much!

Comment: @AlexanderKondratskiy Hey, looks like all I needed was a QCoreApplication::processEvents() in my infinite loop to fix it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: QPlainTextEdit is known to be slow, specially if you use QPlainTextEdit::setMaximumBlockCount()

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem before. In my case, and from my experience, the Signal/Slot System seems to lock the program flow. When you read in a lot of data or frequently read in some data it will naturally cause the GUI to slow down.

What worked for me was to use model-based input, which allows a steady and smooth update.
You might want to consider relocating the input so that you can directly read from the input to the GUI?